# Mail not send in email id but also didn't give any error

Tags: php, email

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "chirag.shukal252@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

This is my code for sending mail.
/*The mail function not give any error but mail not send to given email id.
Please help me to solve it.*/

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure the server you're running this on has enabled sendmail for PHP?

Comment: Might not be, but if you're working in xampp or wampp then mail() won't work out of the box

Comment: I got the solution.My server not allowed to send the php mail.

Comment: Thank you for solving the error.